# Geometric Interpretation of Image

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the geometric Interpretation of the image of the following linear mapping?
               $f: \bf R^3 \to\bf R^3$  with $f(x,y,z)=f(x-y+z,-x+2y+z,y+2z)$

Comment: are you sure you want "f" on the right-hand side?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the *entire* image, it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which means it could be a point, a line through the origin, a plane through the origin, or the whole space. The answer is given by the rank of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. If it is zero, the image is a point, if it is 1, the image is a line, etc. You can compute the rank by row reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is of the form $f(\vec x)=A\vec x$ where
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
The image of $f$ is the column space of $A$, which we will denote by $\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}\Col(A)$. Since the columns of $A$ are vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ we know that $\Col(A)$ is a *subspace* of $\Bbb R^3$.

To find a basis for $\Col(A)$, we can row-reduce $A$. This row-reduction gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
The pivot columns of the reduced row-echelon form of $A$ correspond to the location of basis vectors in the columns of $A$. In this case we see that $\Col(A)$ is a three dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. Of course, the only such subspace is $\Bbb R^3$ itself!

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

Since z* = x* + y* , we have sphere mapped to a cylinder etc... (forgot its name)